Will the natural or artificial magnets degrades or loses it's magnetic property over time or when used for induction?
Will the natural or artificial magnets degrades or loses it's magnetic property
when used for purposes like magnetizing other artificial magnet, generating electricity in wind turbines/hydro power, etc,..
ie) when it's magnetic energy is used for any productive purpose.
In the attached question as duplicate I see cases like de magnetization like heating, hammering, friction, applying voltage without extracting any useful work from the magnetic energy.
I got to know from the duplicate question that overtime it loses magnetic energy due to any existing thermal conditions and it will be very slow process to happen naturally.
But still I have a doubt that if the magnetic energy is consumed to perform some useful purpose like magnetizing other magnetic material to make new artificial magnets or for generating electricity.
Will the magnetic energy consumed will make it lose it's magnetic property based on the consumption level?

yes and yes. That is why serious electrical generators are never made with permanent magnets.

This question is similar to: Do magnets wear out?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@naturallyInconsistent If by "serious" you mean "high power", then you are misjudging the engineering criteria. It's mostly a matter of cost. Suitable magnetic materials are quite expensive and it makes no sense to deploy them for low frequency electric machinery that has a rather low power density. Iron/transformer steel plus a bit of extra copper is much, much cheaper. There is another advantage: we can control the output voltage of the generator (which is load dependent) with the excitation current. That is not possible with permanent magnetic machines.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/824515/123208

Your edited question (v3) is different from the current marked duplicate, but it is still a duplicate of many questions. Examples: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1503/174766, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59429/174766, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251114/174766, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445214/174766, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/467437/174766, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/824515/174766, among others. Voting to leave closed.

Someone with the ability to edit the duplicate list should do so.
